# Graph - when I am creating event in outlook through microsoft graph api it returns lastModifiedDateTime which changes continuously for some seconds?

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

First I add event in microsoft outlook through graph api :

The response return is following :

```
{
     "eventId":"AAMkADVmMTRhZGJjLTA0M2QtNU5NzMyOTg",
     "lst_mod_date_time":"2020-03-04T07:12:35.6095734Z"
}
```

Now I get all events through microsoft graph explorer

The response is following :

```
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"sdfasfdsadfsdfasdfasfsafsdfs==\"",
    "id": "fsadkfhkashfkahfkhsafd8897979fasdfasfdasf",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-03-04T07:12:35.5486075Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-04T07:13:21.6715217Z",
    "subject": "Outlook Plugin"
}
```

Now compare lastModifiedDateTime of both responses.
Why lastModifiedDateTime is changing continuously after saving event in outlook?
I want to save lastModifiedDateTime at the time of creating event in outlook into my database so that I can compare it when I sync events another time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, `lastModifiedDateTime` will have a small change after you successfully created the event. I think it's because the background data is still not processed at this time.

But after you get the second `lastModifiedDateTime`, it won't change any more **until you modify the event**.

So you need to make sure that no changes happen in this event.

Comment: Exactly happening to me but my concern is that after creating event it takes more than 10 seconds to make lastModifiedDateTime stable ! and I am using lastModifiedDateTime as last sync time.
For solving this issue I was thinking of using sleep of 3 secs but 10 sec or + is long time

Comment: @amitsuyal I think it's the limitation if you need to use `lastModifiedDateTime` currently. BTW, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I get correctly but, if you are using the API to create an event in your/someone else's calendar then the lastModifiedDateTime should return a value and that will continue to be same until you modify it from any client like outlook/owa/api.

Comment: No lastModifiedDateTime takes some time to get stable after creating event